# how data is interpreted in computers

Tags: interpretation

Something that troubles me when I think of is how incoming data is interpreted in computers. I searched a lot but could not find an answer so as a last resort I am asking in here. What I am saying is that you plug in a USB to your computer and data stream starts. Your computer receives ones and zeros from the USB and interpret them correctly like for example inside of the USB there are pictures with different names and different formats and resolutions. What I do not understand is how computer correctly puts them together and the big picture emerges. This could be seen as a stupid question but had me thinking for a while. How does this system work?

I am not a computer scientist but I am studying Electrical and electronics engineering and know somethings.

Comment: It's great that you're interested in the topic, but this is a much larger question than could reasonably be answered here. You might get a general idea of how it works from this type of forum, but the full answer would basically be a bachelor's degree worth of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all just streams of ones and zeros, which get counted up into bytes.  As you probably know one can multiplex them, but with modern hardware that isn't very necessary (the 's' in USB standing for 'serial)

A pure black and white image of an "A" would be a 2d array:

```
111
101
111
101
101
```

[3x5 font](https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/716744/3_by_5_pixel_font)

I would guess that "A" is stored in a font file as `111101111101101`, with a known length of 3*5=15 bits.

When displayed in a window, that A would be broken down into lines, and inserted on the respective line of the window, becoming a stream which contains 320x256 pixels perhaps.

When the length of data is not constant, it can:

- If there is a max size, could be the size of the max size (integers and other primitive data types do this, a `0` takes 32/64 bits, as does `400123`)
- A length is included somewhere, often a sort of "header"
- It gets chunked up into either constant or variable sized chunks, and has a continue bit (UTF-8 is a good simple example of constant chunks, some networking protocols (maybe TCP/IP) are a good example of variable chunks)

Both sides need to know how to decode the data, in your example of a USB stick with an image on it.  The operating system has a driver which understands the UUID is a storage device, and attempts to read [special sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) from it.  If it detects a partition type it recognizes (for windows that would be NTFS or FAT32), it will then load the file tables, using drivers that understand how to decode those.  It finds a filename allows access via the filename.  Then an image reading program is able to load the bytestream of that file and decode it using [its headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) and installed codecs into a raster image array.  If any of those pieces are not available in your system, you cannot view the image, and it will be just any random binary to you (if you format the usb stick with Linux, or use a uncommon/old image format)

So its all various level of explicit or implicit handshakes to agree on what the data is when you get to the higher levels (higher level being at least once you agree on [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and baudrate of data transmission)